# How to go Live from sandbox account for Braintree?

Tags: node.js, paypal, braintree

How to go Live from the sandbox account for Braintree?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a live Braintree account? To get one, have the business owner contact Braintree via https://www.braintreepayments.com/

It will have its own live credentials.